# How to Center align Menu in Twenty ten default WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, twenty-ten-theme

IS it possible to align menu item center? Actually my website has a lot many menus, So menus are appearing on second line from left so I want to show them as center aligned.Any suggestions?
Please find below my Css. This is edited style sheet of default twenty ten wordpress theme. I am using full width layout.
Thanks.

```css
#access {
 background:#cc0000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  border-top:2px solid #eb9999;
 border-bottom:12px solid #000000;
 clear:both;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
#access .menu-header,
div.menu {
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1024px;
}
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#access a {
 color: #aaa;
 display: block;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul{display:inline-block;}
#access ul ul {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 38px;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul li {
 min-width: 180px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
 background: #333;
 line-height: 1em;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 160px;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, in order to do that, you will need to use css.  If you want to give more details, you'll get an even better answer.

Comment: Hey JakeParis, Thank you for your reply. Please find below my css: